# Converting equation of summations to matrix operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, summation, matrix-equations

I am struggling to understand the steps to vectorise a series of summations over several matrices, as applied to a machine learning algorithm. Though I have the final form, for my own benefit I want to understand how this is done.

Assuming the following:

- $A$ is a $n \times n$ graph adjacency matrix, where $n$ denotes the number of nodes and $A_{ij}$ is the matrix element at $(i,j)$
- $B$ is a $c \times n$ matrix where $n$ is the number of samples (nodes), $c$ is the number of possible labels
- $C$ is a $n \times n$ matrix, for our purposes here it is the same as a $n \times n$ Identity matrix
- $D$ represents the graph node degree matrix

So the equation is as follows,

$\hat{B} = \sum_{i}\sum_{j}A_{ij}\sum_{k}(B_{ik} - \sum_{l}B_{jl}C_{lk})^{2}$

This allegedly yields the following, when the above is translated into a series of matrix operations:

$\hat{B} = \mathtt{tr}(B^TDB - 2B^TABC + C^TB^TDBC)$

I cannot figure out how to arrive at this formulation, as I get confused with the outer summation over the term in brackets $\sum_{k}( \cdots )$ and the negative inner summation $ - \sum_{l}( \cdots )$ as it uses the $j$ from a summation on the far left.

Comment: Mind if I comment some observations$?$ $1$) I believe matrix $B$ is actually $c\times n$ instead of $n\times c$, otherwise the products $C^{\rm T}B^{\rm T}$ and $BC$ are impossible. $2$) You can identify the range of the indices just by the dimensions of the matrices. $3$) If $C$ is an identity matrix, why not just call it $I?$ $3$ bis) If so, then $\hat B$ can actually be simplified as $$\hat B =2\text{ tr }(B^{\rm T}(D-A)B) =2\text{ tr }(B^{\rm T}DB) -2\text{ tr }(B^{\rm T}AB).$$ $4$) It may be easier to start from the matrix operations rather than from the summations.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comments @Rócherz. I use **C** distinct from **I** as it may not necessarily always be equal to **I**. The values on the principal diagonal may be [0, 1], though I hoped to make my question simpler by stating for our purposes here C = I.

Comment: Actually, it does matter how $C$ differs from $I$. The exactness of the computations may depend on it. What is $C$ exactly?

Comment: Perhaps we could move this conversation to chat? It might be easier and I appreciate your help greatly